# angular route is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular route is not working for me..

My JS:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var chatApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
chatApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/index', {
            templateUrl : 'index.html',
            controller  : 'mainCtrl'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/chat', {
            templateUrl : 'views/chat.html',
            controller  : 'chatCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'});
});

chatApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

chatApp.controller('chatCtrl', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});
```

In Html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Added my scripts also.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-resource.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-route.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>


URL : ...goaway-web/app/chat  Example what I am trying. 
goaway-web/app/index
```

While redirecting or directly entering the URL it is not working..
Please help!!

Comment: did you get any error on your console?

Comment: Do you have ng-view?

Comment: @ShamalPerera . I agree with you. :=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with #.

**Sample :**
`<a href="#/index">SOME_DETAIL</a>`

And please check, do you have implement `ng-view` on your `index.html`

Comment: Can we see your anchor tag href with code? and tell us your application correct path. (what you eamn by `view`)?